# Passing data from parent to child in React using useState problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

I have a parent functional component from which I open a dialog with one required field(Fluent UI DatePicker). I have a fun that monitors changes in DatePicker, and sends value to parent where I do my validation like this

```
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(false)

function isDatePickerFieldEmpty() {
        if (props.DueDate === undefined || props.DueDate === null) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    function isDatePickerValid():Boolean {
        var counter = 0;
        if(!isDatePickerFieldEmpty()){
            setErrorMessage(true)
            counter++
        } else {
            setErrorMessage(false)
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

//function that triggers from dialog on Submit click
 const saveData = () => {
        if(isDatePickerValid()){
            //save function
        }
    }
```

The idea is that when isDatePickerValid returns false, a TRUE is sent to child dialog via props, and there I conditionally render error messages and styles for the field. And that works. The problem is when I do this in my dialog

```
 const submitClicked = () => {
        props.saveData();
        if(props.errorMessage){
            setHideDialog(false)
            props.hideDateDialog(true)
        } else {
            setHideDialog(true)
            props.hideDateDialog(false)
}
    };
```

When I click submit in Dialog, it triggers a save fun in parent, and save fun should trigger setErrorMessage to true or false, and send it to dialog. But error message data is late. For example, if I dont enter a date, and click submit, it should send TRUE to dialog, and do the styling for required field, and not close the dialog. Instead, it sends FALSE to dialog and closed it, and when i open dialog again, then it sends TRUE and activates conditional styling. My errorMessage from parent is late. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

React updates are `batched` so even though your code is synchronous, state update is done in the next tick. So when you call `props.saveData` you need to wait one *render* of the component to access new props data.
`props.errorMessage` is not immediately updated.

```js
const submitClicked = () => {
        props.saveData();
        props.errorMessage)// this is stale value
    };
```

What you need to do is **listen** to changes for `props.errorMessage` via `useEffect` hook, and then respond to it accordingly. Something like this:

```js
 const submitClicked = () => {
        props.saveData();
    };

useEffect(()=>{
   if(props.errorMessage){
     setHideMessage(true)
   }else{
     setHideMessage(false)
   }
},[props.errorMessage])
```

You will also probably need to change your logic a little bit so that you can disambiguate when `errorMessage` is `false` because the data haven't been saved yet, and because `save` is done, and there is no error.